# How to set selectedIndex of select element using display text?

Tags: javascript, selectedindex

How to set selectedIndex of select element using display text as reference?

Example:

```
<input id="AnimalToFind" type="text" />
<select id="Animals">
    <option value="0">Chicken</option>
    <option value="1">Crocodile</option>
    <option value="2">Monkey</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="SelectAnimal()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectAnimal()
    {
        //Set selected option of Animals based on AnimalToFind value...
    }
 </script>
```

Is there any other way to do this without a loop? You know, I'm thinking of a built-in JavaScript code or something. Also, I don't use jQuery...

Comment: The loop is working, but I wonder is there any way I can do it without a loop? And also, no jQuery?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try this:

```
function SelectAnimal() {
    var sel = document.getElementById('Animals');
    var val = document.getElementById('AnimalToFind').value;
    for(var i = 0, j = sel.options.length; i < j; ++i) {
        if(sel.options[i].innerHTML === val) {
           sel.selectedIndex = i;
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No loop, no jQuery, is it possible?

Comment: Why do you use that `j` there?

Comment: @JuanLuisSoldi So I don't recalculate `sel.options.length` more times than I absolutely have to.

Comment: @JacobRelkin I know this is an old post, but I felt that I needed to point out that `sel.options.length` does not calculate anything as it it is not a function. You are accessing a variable contained in the `sel.options` object. The `j = sel.options.length` is not necessary.

Answer (score 9):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function SelectAnimal(){
         //Set selected option of Animals based on AnimalToFind value...
         var animalTofind = document.getElementById('AnimalToFind');
         var selection = document.getElementById('Animals');

        // select element
        for(var i=0;i<selection.options.length;i++){
            if (selection.options[i].innerHTML == animalTofind.value) {
                selection.selectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
     }
</script>
```

setting the selectedIndex property of the select tag will choose the correct item. it is a good idea of instead of comparing the two values (options innerHTML && animal value) you can use the indexOf() method or regular expression to select the correct option despite casing or presense of spaces

```
selection.options[i].innerHTML.indexOf(animalTofind.value) != -1;
```

or using `.match(/regular expression/)`

Comment: Hm, is there any other way to do this without a loop? You know, I'm thinking of a built-in JavaScript code or something. Also, I don't use jQuery...

Comment: actually this loop is effective because as soon as the condition is met, the loop stops. thats why i use the `break;` command

Comment: A while ago, I can't (not enough reputation). But now you commented, I gained reputation or privileges rather, I voted your answer up.

Comment: selection.value = animalTofind.value; // is what I have used in TypeScript projects and it seem to work fine in regard to finding the correct index

Answer (score 4):

If you want this without loops or jquery you could use the following
This is straight up JavaScript. This works for current web browsers. Given the age of the question I am not sure if this would have worked back in 2011. Please note that using css style selectors is extremely powerful and can help shorten a lot of code.

```js
// Please note that querySelectorAll will return a match for 
// for the term...if there is more than one then you will 
// have to loop through the returned object
var selectAnimal = function() {
  var animals = document.getElementById('animal');
  if (animals) {
    var x = animals.querySelectorAll('option[value="frog"]');
    if (x.length === 1) {
      console.log(x[0].index);
      animals.selectedIndex = x[0].index;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test without loop or jquery</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label>Animal to select
  <select id='animal'>
    <option value='nothing'></option>
    <option value='dog'>dog</option>
    <option value='cat'>cat</option>
    <option value='mouse'>mouse</option>
    <option value='rat'>rat</option>
    <option value='frog'>frog</option>
    <option value='horse'>horse</option>
  </select>
  </label>
  <button onclick="selectAnimal()">Click to select animal</button>

</body>

</html>
```

document.getElementById('Animal').querySelectorAll('option[value="searchterm"]');
in the index object you can now do the following:
x[0].index

Comment: Could just use CSS selector `select#animals > option[value="frog"]` and save yourself a few lines.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function SelectAnimal()
{
    var animals = document.getElementById('Animals');
    var animalsToFind = document.getElementById('AnimalToFind');
    // get the options length
    var len = animals.options.length;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      // check the current option's text if it's the same with the input box
      if (animals.options[i].innerHTML == animalsToFind.value)
      {
         animals.selectedIndex = i;
         break;
      }     
    }
}
```

Comment: could have cached the document.getElementById :)

Comment: Hm, is there any other way to do this without a loop? You know, I'm thinking of a built-in JavaScript code or something. Also, I don't use jQuery...

Comment: @naveen, true, now applied to be neater ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the index by this code :

```
sel.selectedIndex = 0;
```

but remember a caution in this practice, You would not be able to call the server side `onclick` method if you select the previous value selected in the drop down..

Answer (score 0):

Add name attribute to your option:

```
<option value="0" name="Chicken">Chicken</option>
```

With that you can use the HTMLOptionsCollection.namedItem("Chicken").value to set the value of your select element.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the HTMLOptionsCollection.namedItem()
That means that you have to define your select options to have a name attribute and have the value of the displayed text.
e.g 
    California