# Select menu options aren't shown or hidden as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a simple little script that should allow a drop down list to enable/ disable the second dropdown list with the relevant data, but it is not working correctly.

Here is all the code and html:

```
$("[name='pet_type']").change(function () {
    var pet_type = $(this).val();
    $("[name='breed']").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("select[name='breed'] > option").each(function () {
        var o = $(this);
        console.log(o.data('pet-type'));
        console.log(pet_type);
        if (o.data('pet-type') === pet_type) {
            o.hide();
        } else {
            o.show();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select name="pet_type">
    <option></option>
    <option value="Cat" data-pet-type="Cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="Dog" data-pet-type="Dog">Dog</option>
</select>
<select name="breed" disabled="disabled">
    <option></option>
    <option data-pet-type="Cat" disabled="disabled">--- Cat Breeds</option>
    <option value="Chartreux" data-pet-type="Cat">Chartreux</option>
    <option value="Cymric" data-pet-type="Cat">Cymric</option>
    <option data-pet-type="Dog" disabled="disabled">--- Dog Breeds</option>
    <option value="Affenpinscher" data-pet-type="Dog">Affenpinscher</option>
    <option value="Anatolian Shepherd Dog" data-pet-type="Dog">Anatolian Shepherd Dog</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

All that is happening is when you click on an option is the first downdrop, it just enables the second dropdown with all the data for cats and dogs, when really it should only enable data for the 1 option that is selected.

If anyone has any ideas on why this is not working correctly that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the final HTML output, with the PHP rendered, instead?

Comment: So its not really doing nothing, it is doing something that you expected would be something else :)

Comment: @WesleyMurch If I'm not mistaken, he wouldn't have had any JS errors anyway.

Comment: Appreciate reply. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simply that you can't hide individual `option` tags in most browsers. Instead, you can [disable them](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/eWx2D/):

```
o.prop('disabled',true); // or false
```

or [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) the unwanted options [and re-attach them later](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/h6kLY/):

```
window.all_options = $("[name='breed'] > option").detach(); // global variable

$("[name='pet_type']").change(function () {
    var pet_type = $(this).val();
    $("[name='breed']").removeAttr("disabled").append(window.all_options);
    $("select[name='breed'] > option").each(function () {
        var o = $(this);
        if (o.data('pet-type') !== pet_type) {
            o.detach();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Here is a fixed demo (with slightly cleaner JavaScript) http://jsfiddle.net/UUd55/2/

Comment: And yes I looked up cat and dog breeds to make the HTML :)

Comment: I have now done this. I got the code from an email my brother sent me.

Comment: I meant I got the original code from an email that is why there was smart-quotes. Blazemonger, that worked an absolute charm! thank you very much.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would it be difficult to make the script so when you choose cat or dog in the first dropdown, it automatically jumps to the relevant list in the drop down? So if you selected cat it would automatically jump to the Cat Breed list?

Comment: Yes, you can change the selected option with `.prop('selected', true/false)`, or simply set the `.val(newval)` on the `select` element. The vanilla-JS approach is to set [`select.selectedIndex`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6210390/901048)

Comment: I have just seen the 'and re-attach them later' part. Tested, checked and looks perfect. Thank you Blazemonger!